# Office 365 sharepoint List connection in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to connect Office 365 sharepoint List in Visual Studio.
But am not able to connect. Is there any solution for this?
Or this is not possible at all?

Many Thanks
Savita

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can even deploy apps directly to your office 365 (sharepoint online). Just make sure that you give in your URL of the sharepoint site in visual studio in its project properties. It will then prompt for authentication. Put them in and you're good to go.

Comment: I am confused about the sharepoint url. I tried putting the entire sharepoint url and also tried with just a till List name, but no luck, am not sure why its not working, it gives authentication error. But I have access to sharepoint .

Comment: I hope you already do not have any saved passwords. In that case, do a cache and cookie clearing from all your browsers. What version of visual studio are you using?